# Malformed config.xml in phonegap build when upload apps

Tags: xml, cordova, phonegap-build

When I am trying to upload my app to phonegap build it doesn't work. It gives me error of malfunctioned config.xml

You can check my config file here

```
<widget 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" 
xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" 
id="com.crondale.tippnett" 
android-versionCode="3728"
version="1.1.19">
<name>TippNett</name>
<description>TippNett er et system for å som bidrar til bedre massebalanse. Systemet finner anlegg i nærheten med motsatt massebehov. Det bidrar til kortere kjørelengde og raskere anleggsutførsel. Du sparer penger, i tillegg til at miljøet blir spart for CO2 utslipp.</description>


</widget>
```

It was working before and all of a sudden it doesn't work, can any one explain me why this has happened?

After checking it seems like it is because of the special characters I have in my description tags like æ,å etc.Any reason for it not working all of a sudden?

Answer (score 0):

I can't find special issues in your code, anyway I got the following line code at the top of my config.xml, maybe you could manage to change the encoding for your special case:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
// After this line I got <widget etc etc
```

Comment: I tried adding that, but it doesn't work. If I remove the special characters from my description tags then it works.

Comment: I had to change encoding of my file. :)